# No log output Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

A few days ago my Qt Creator stopped to display log output. I didn't change any settings and it seems to be a proplem with the whole project, as my teammates had the same issue after checking out the latest version from GIT. Changing back to a former version does not solve the issue! Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work if you just run your application from a terminal?  If it's affecting everyone using the project the most likely reason is simply that something changed which stops the logging going to stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 2):

I has same issue. My answer is very simple...
Make sure your selected build kit is `Debug` not `Release` :)  [image: Build kit]

Comment: What if I want to build it in release mode (say to check performance measurements) ?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether stderr/stdout have been redirected anywhere in the program. I have code that does that intentionally using `freopen` for my error handler to redirect `stderr` to a text file since I have no console.

While in debug mode, I make sure to print both to the Qt Creator console and to the text file.